# HOWTO look 'Session Login Items' in swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

i am trying to get the list of Session Login Items to see if the current application is already registered, but something goes wrong....

Here is a snapshot of the code:

```
var loginItems : LSSharedFileListRef=LSSharedFileListCreate(nil, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems!.takeUnretainedValue(), nil)!.takeUnretainedValue()

var seed :UInt32 = 0
var theLoginItemsRef=loginItems as LSSharedFileListRef
var loginItemsArray=LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(theLoginItemsRef, &seed).takeUnretainedValue()

for item in (loginItemsArray as NSArray){
    var itemRef  = item as LSSharedFileListItemRef
    var url=LSSharedFileListItemCopyResolvedURL(itemRef,0,nil).takeUnretainedValue()
    // do something with url
}
```

it compiles, but at runtime it complains because of the Downcasting (var itemRef  = item as LSSharedFileListItemRef) and crashes.
(The loginItems gets the type of __NSCFType (??!!?) does it matters?)

it gives me the following error:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x66fb, 0x000000010db218a6 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastUnknownClassUnconditional + 134, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
* frame #0: 0x000000010db218a6 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastUnknownClassUnconditional + 134
  frame #1: 0x000000010ddb1bb4 $__lldb_expr65`top_level_code + 2996 at playground65.swift:20
  frame #2: 0x000000010ddb1e61 $__lldb_expr65`main + 49 at <EXPR>:0
...
```

Any suggestions?